# Kotlin Lambdas: как "собрать" коллекцию объектов в один объект?

Tags: kotlin, lambda

У меня есть объект:

```
data class DayNutrientsDto(val proteins: Double,
                            val carbohydrates: Double,
                            val fats: Double,
                            val calories: Int,
                            val userId: Long,
                            val date: LocalDate)
```

У меня есть коллекция таких объектов, предположим, `list`. Мне нужно сложить все поля объектов, с такими же полями

```
proteins + proteins + proteins..., fats + fats + fats...
```

и получить один объект вместо коллекции. Подскажите, как это сделать через lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Операцией Reduce бежим по списку и каждый раз возвращаем новый объект.

Пример для proteins, для других также:

```
data class DayNutrientsDto(val proteins: Double,
                            val carbohydrates: Double = 1.0,
                            val fats: Double = 1.1,
                            val calories: Int = 1,
                            val userId: Long = 1,
                            val date: LocalDate = LocalDate.now())

fun main() {
    val l = listOf(
        DayNutrientsDto(0.1),
        DayNutrientsDto(0.2),
        DayNutrientsDto(0.3),
        DayNutrientsDto(0.4),
        DayNutrientsDto(0.5)
    )
    val k = l.reduce{ acc, el ->
        DayNutrientsDto(acc.proteins + el.proteins)
    }
    println(k)
}
```